# How to perform binary "or" operations on column of Data Frame in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let me explain you the scenario:

I am creating one mask value. i.e.

```
val Date = 20170501
val day = Date.toString.substring(6, 8)
val mask = pow(2, day.toInt -1)
```

Then next I am creating `dataframe` which create additional column using `withColumn` i.e.

```
val t1 = df.withColumn("C1", when($"a1" > 0 , $"C1" | mask.toInt).otherwise($"C1"))
```

but when I am performing `|` operation with `Dataframe` column it is giving me error as "`value | is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName`".

early help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [bitwiseOR](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#bitwiseOR(other:Any):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) which is implemented by `Column` :

```
val t1 = df.withColumn("C1", when($"a1" > 0 , $"C1".bitwiseOR(mask.toInt)).otherwise($"C1"))
```

Comment: Thanks.. the link which you provided solves my purpose. actually i am trying to do bitwise or and not able tot find to achieve it. by going through docs i got my answer.